# How to find when "Function" (date) is added to responsibility Oracle EBS 12.1.3

Tags: oracle-ebs

I was adding new Menu functions to Responsibility and then i updated wrong one. But not sure if it is updated now or it was there before.

So, I am searching for a query to find when a certain menu function is added to the certain responsibility.

Please help me.

Comment: Anyone Please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL query access, the who columns (audit columns) are a good place to start looking - check out the LAST_UPDATE_DATE for the date the modification was made and LAST_UPDATED_BY will tell you who updated the table.  All the tables should have them.  The tables involved are:

- fnd_menu
- fnd_menu_entry
- fnd_nodes
- fnd_user_resp_groups
- fnd_resp_function
- fnd_responsibility